# Batch script and SYSTEM user

Tags: windows, vpn, batch-file

I have small problem with my script running on first login on Win7 machines. The script is written in batch. 
Now, I am making VPN connection during first login but the script runs under the SYSTEM user and my script needs to know username of the currently logged user to be able to set proper VPN credentials. Is there any way like %username% in batch to find this real username?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: if the script is running under system, that **is** the real user in its opinion. you will need to pass the username in as a argument to your script.

Comment: But how should I do it? If I don't know the username of currently logged user.

Comment: how are you scheduling it? don't execute under the system account.

Comment: Well I hive a registry and under the RunOnce I have a key with command "CMD /C %SYSTEMROOT%\path-to-something\MASTER.BAT"

Comment: ahh, yeah, there is no way you can identify a user from there, since there will be many service users logged into the system at that time. I'd use the task scheduler to run it at login, and check to see if the connection is already established before dialing up a new one.